# Running Python on GPU using numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba, numba-pro

I am trying to run python code in my NVIDIA GPU and googling seemed to tell me that numbapro was the module that I am looking for. However, according to [this](https://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/), numbapro is no longer continued but has been moved to the numba library. I tried out numba and it's `@jit` decorator does seem to speed up some of my code very much. However, as I read up on it more, it seems to me that `jit` simply compiles your code during run-time and in doing so, it does some heavy optimization and hence the speed-up.

This is further re-enforced by the fact that `jit` does not seem to speed up the already optimized numpy operations such as `numpy.dot` etc.

Am I getting confused and way off the track here? What exactly does `jit` do? And if it does not make my code run on the GPU, how else do I do it?

Comment: You should really read the docs, this topic is explained there very well. Spoiler: you actually _can_ run code on GPU, just keep reading.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specifically tell Numba to target the GPU, either via a ufunc:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/ufunc.html

or by programming your functions in a way that explicitly takes the GPU into account:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/examples.html
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/index.html

The plain `jit` function does not target the GPU and will typically not speed-up calls to things like `np.dot`. Typically Numba excels where you can either avoid creating intermediate temporary numpy arrays or if the code you are writing is hard to write in a vectorized fashion to begin with.